# Making call from PC via bluetooth connected mobile phone

Tags: android, macos, mobile, raspberry-pi, gsm

I am looking to build a system to make call's (prefer programatically) from PC via bluetooth/USB connected mobile phone. Its a regular cellular call from my phone to another phone number....and NOT looking for VOIP call..i.e call over internet..

it could be even making phone call from raspberry pi to usb connected mobile phone

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want the phone to be able to originate the call using your PC, but then use the phone's audio (speaker, microphone and/or headphones) then this is possible. You can use AT commands to set up the cal.

> D [T|P|digits|misc].

where T or P means Tone or Pulse dealing. (e.g. https://www.dialogic.com/webhelp/diva/9.6lin/206-324-15/at-command_set.htm)

If you want to want the audio to also be on the PC then you would need some form of gateway on the phone to act as the bridge between the GSM network and a VoIP or Voice over serial port connection to your PC. I am not aware of any commonly available gateway and certainly not one that would be supported universally on any phone.